# "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error after post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

need help with some weird error

this is express , nodejs service that hosted on heroku

this is my route controller code

```
async function PopupConroller(req, res) {


        let credential = req.credential;
        let zoho_token = null;
        console.log('res :>> ', res);
        try {
            zoho_token  = await axios.post(`https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token?client_id=${credential.client_id}&client_secret=${credential.client_secret}&refresh_token=${credential.refresh_token}&grant_type=refresh_token`);
            console.log('zoho_token.data :>> ', zoho_token.data);

        } catch (error) {
            console.log('ex 2 :>> ',error);
        }
        console.log('res :>> ', res);


       res.status(200).json({status:"ok"});

       return;
```

}

when service received request, code throws this error
**(no error from axios.post request)**

the response back : 200 OK with no body

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
 at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:530:11)
 at ServerResponse.header (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
 at ServerResponse.json (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:264:10)
 at PopupConroller (/app/voicenter.js:261:28)
 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

---

when removing those lines everything is ok
response: 200 OK with {status:"ok"}

```
async function PopupConroller(req, res) {


        let credential = req.credential;
        let zoho_token = null;
        console.log('res1 :>> ', res);
        try {
            //zoho_token  = await axios.post(`https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token?client_id=${credential.client_id}&client_secret=${credential.client_secret}&refresh_token=${credential.refresh_token}&grant_type=refresh_token`);
            //console.log('zoho_token.data :>> ', zoho_token.data);

        } catch (error) {
            console.log('ex 2 :>> ',error);
        }
        console.log('res2 :>> ', res);


       res.status(200).json({status:"ok"});

       return;
```

}

in the first example,
When I checked the res object (console.log res1) the headers not sent, but in the second (console.log res2) I noticed that the response headers sent back.

WAY THIS LINE SENT THE HEADERS???
***need to say that similar code in other routes work prefect**

```
zoho_token  = await axios.post(`https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token?client_id=${credential.client_id}&client_secret=${credential.client_secret}&refresh_token=${credential.refresh_token}&grant_type=refresh_token`);
```

appreciate the help...
thanks

Comment: I understand the error, but I do not understand what you are trying to say. Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: What exactly is on the line 261 in your /app/voicenter.js file? Also do you have an error handler set in express which might kick in? When you get this error it means some response was sent back to the client so does the client recieve any data?

Comment: the error came from one of the middleware , there was res.end() with no return after , by adding the return statement after it solved the error.
but i am still not sure way just this rout had error , because i used the  same middlwares for couple of routes. 
nevertheless thank you for your responses.

Comment: @TalWeizman can you please expand on the above comment? I am not clear about the real issue here. `PopupController` is a promise that should `resolve` with a token. You are ending the response with a status code 200 and a json object when in fact this function is the promise you should use in whatever handler is **calling** it. Can you share the  `handler` that is calling `PopupController`? It is there you should end the response, not in your promise...

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing here, is that what you want?

To expand on the snippet code below, you get the error `cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` because `axios.post()` is making **the** HTTP post request.

In your code, you make an HTTP call via axios so the headers get sent out.

After that, the JS parser continues the evaluation of the code and after the try block, because there is no error, it evaluates the res.status() for a response that has been already sent, hence the error.

So, to solve this issue, you can handle the post request as you do, **without** resending the response again to the client. You can then "do something" with the promise response within the ´thenable´ function.

If you want to post an optional object via axios, you can do this by passing the argument into the post request.

```
async function PopupConroller(req, res) {

        let credential = req.credential;
        let zoho_token = await axios.post("whatever", {"cat": "meaows"})
        .then((response)=> {
            // do something with the response
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  
}
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Is that a rethorical question?

Comment: Seems like my comment worked since you added details explaining it after I wrote it ;)

Comment: Yes, I realised that the user needed an explanation for the error so I added it. Thank you

Comment: the error came from one of the middleware , there was res.end() with no return after , by adding the return statement after it solved the error.
but i am still not sure way just this rout had error , because i used the  same middlwares for couple of routes. 
nevertheless thank you for your response.